# Laravel 5 how to include autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to include a path to autoload.php which is in

```
vendor/autoload.php
```

the file trying to access it is in

```
public/this-file.php
```

I set the path to `require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';` but it just throws the error -

```
Warning: require_once(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php55/lib/php')
```

Does laravel offer a shortcode to access files in the vendor file

Comment: Why and where are you trying to include `autoload.php`?  Why can't you use `composer.json` to add your dependencies?

Comment: I used composer require to grab the package I needed, which it has but I need to include the autoload too right?

Comment: Try `php artisan dump-autoload` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Try `require_once 'C:\Users\Dell\vendor\autoload.php';` (specify username in my case its 'Dell') and then run  `$composer update` and `$composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need to require `autoload.php` in a Laravel application, it's already being required. You can just add more package in your `composer.json`  file or do a `composer require`  in the command line, and it should work.

It is required in `bootstrap/autoload.php`, if you don't believe me. ;)

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------  -----
| Register The Composer Auto Loader
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------    -
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

If it doesn't for some reason, try `composer dump-autoload`, which fixes a lot of "requiring" issues in Laravel, especially when working with seeders and that sort of thing.

Comment: Aha I see now thanks! I used the composer require and have the package, but how can I tell my app to include a class thats inside the package.

Comment: You should be able to use it directly, if you can't then make sure that you're using the proper namespace. Look into your library files to see what namespace it's using, but you should be able to find it on their documentation if they have any.

Comment: I have the same problem: require(F:\Xamp\htdocs\getme-backend-new\public/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream.
This is my error. Can you please tell me how to solve that?