# In PHP, where do you initialize your autoloaded modules?

Tags: php, laravel

New to PHP. Trying to implement a simple Slack integration using Laravel.
Successfully added `alek13/slack` following instructions [here](https://packagist.org/packages/alek13/slack) and confirmed it's in my project's `composer.json` file. According to the guidance:

---

Quick Tour

- create an incoming webhook & copy hook_url
- `composer require alek13/slack`
- add the following code

```php
use Maknz\Slack\Client;
require(__DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Client('https://hook_url');
$client->to('#general')->send('Good morning');
```

Done!

---

While this may be obvious to PHP veterans, I am unable to gather from the documentation any reference as to exactly into which file the sample code above should be inserted. (e.g., `./vendor/autoload.php`? `./config/...`?, etc.)

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`This answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32575801/1779433) sheds some light on exactly how Laravel requires `vendor/autoload.php`. (It's required in `bootstrap/autoload.php`).

That being the case, you can just `use Maknz\Slack\Client` in the PHP file you need the `Client` class in, and initialize it there. (Or, consider a [dependency injection pattern](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container) if multiple files will require the same instance.)

(Under the hood, Composer is using [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to register its own [`ClassLoader`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/main/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php) class, in case you're interested in more of the guts of the process.)

Comment: Many thanks for the references - going through them now to see if I can find a suitable solution.  Will do housekeeping on the Answer if/when I solve it. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Cameron_hurd Thank you for the pointer - following these threads helped me down the path. Scope of functions is a bit different for me (especially being new to PHP) but ultimately not too different from other languages.  Found what I needed following "ClassLoader" paradigm. Many thanks!

Comment: Followed links on this topic until I ended up here - this solved my particular problem and answered my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18075712/1244159

Comment: In the end, I skipped the Slack module altogether and built a simple function using the build-in CURL module.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved! FWIW, I've never gone the route detailed in the answer you linked above. It seems like it would be hard to keep track of / rely on and rather nightmarish to deploy any way but "by hand".

Comment: Agreed, but this was a "one-off" to find an "easy" way to pull in some oft-used services for debugging (dumps, Slack messages, other various `curl` stuff).  If time were a luxury, I would have followed a more elegant path.  NOT RECOMMENDED as a solution for proper and long-term projects!! (still, thanks for the pointers!)

Comment: all power to ya